# Deleting all input in the Name Manager after saving external workbook

Tags: vba, save

I am currently making a macro which creates a catalogue and afterwards saves it in different languages as external files. Whenever I save the files with the VBA script below the file is still large (2MB+), but whenever I open the file and delete all references in the Name Manager (these are copied as well it seems), the file is just 30/40 kb.

Is there a VBA formula that automatically deletes the formulas in the Name Manager (only in the external copy, not in the original file!)?

```
Sub NIP_Version()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Workbooks("Opbouw catalogus.xlsm").Activate

filenaam = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Excel prijslijst" & "\" & Sheets("Catalogus").Range("A1").Text & " " & Sheets("Catalogus").Range("G2").Text

'Quotation blad copy
Sheets("Catalogus").Select

'paste as values

Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Dim LastRowNIP As Long
With ActiveSheet
LastRowNIP = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
End With

Set example = Range("A5:G" & LastRowNIP)

example.Value = example.FormulaR1C1

Columns("F").EntireColumn.AutoFit

'Save
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Sheets("Catalogus").Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Copy
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Catalogus").SaveAs Filename:=filenaam, FileFormat:=51

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Sub remove_names()

        Dim xName As Name

            For Each xName In Application.ThisWorkbook.Names

                xName.Delete

            Next xName

     End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Joe, Thanks for helping out. But this does not seem to work yet. I get the mistake message '1004', The name I entered is not valid. I just checked it, but cannot really resolve it yet. Is the naming of the Dim correct? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hi Rob, I have tested this and it works for me. It removes all local names stored in your name manager for me. can you send a screenshot of your names manager and the line "debug error" at which it breaks?

Comment: "xName" in my code snippet could be called anthing you like as long as its referenced correctly it the following lines

Comment: Thanks for helping out. The error I received is: Run-time error '1004' The name that you entered is not valid. Reasons for this can include: -The name does not begin with a letter or an underscore. - The name contains a space or other invalid charachters. -The name conflicts with an Excel built-in name or the name of another object in the workbook.

Comment: I posted it. Already thanks for helping out :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub NIP_Version()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Workbooks("Opbouw catalogus.xlsm").Activate

filenaam = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Excel prijslijst" & "\" & Sheets("Catalogus").Range("A1").Text & " " & Sheets("Catalogus").Range("G2").Text

'Quotation blad Copy
Sheets("Catalogus").Select

'Paste as value

Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Dim LastRowNIP As Long
With ActiveSheet
LastRowNIP = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
End With

Set example = Range("A5:G" & LastRowNIP)

example.Value = example.FormulaR1C1

Columns("F").EntireColumn.AutoFit

'Save
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Sheets("Catalogus").Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Copy
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Catalogus").SaveAs Filename:=filenaam, FileFormat:=51

Sub remove_names()

Dim xName As Name

    For Each xName In Application.ThisWorkbook.Names

            xName.Delete

    Next xName

End Sub

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

Workbooks("Prijslijst maken.xlsm").Activate
```